# Python: file search using dictionary

Tags: python, recursion

I have written a small script to find a file in directories and sub-directories.  I placed these in dictionaries and sub dictionaries within the root dictionary.

So I am trying to find a file within the dictionary of files and sub directories. I am trying to print out contents of this dictionary first then I will be able to modify the code to look for the file within the dictionary.

Here is the code:

```
def recurdd(db):
    for key in db:
        for item in db[key]:
            if hasattr(item,'append'):
                recurdd(item)
            else:
                print key,'=>',db[key]
                print
```

This code prints out the same dictionary all the time which I want to correct.  So if I have a dictionary, i.e.:

```
d = {'a': [{'b': [1, 2, 3]}, {'c': [55, 12, 32]}, 1, 2]}
```

Please assist me with this issue.

Thanks

Comment: What's the expected output? *"This code prints out the same dictionary all the time"* - stop passing it the same dictionary?

Comment: maybe [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.html#os.walk) could also be your friend without using dictionary.

Comment: for the 1st person, how do i pass in another dictionary, this is my problem, so that it would print out the inner dictionaries.??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct code would be:

```
def recurse_directory(dictionary):
    for dirname, dir_content in dictionary.iteritems():
        for filename in dir_content:
            if type(filename) == dict: # It's a directory
                recurse_directory(filename)
            else:
                print "{} => {}".format(dirname, filename)
```